# time series line chart missing rangetool/zoom

Tags: time-series, orange

On the search of the best way to visualize my time series I am currently checking out orange3 . I miss the zoom or a rangetool option as it is shown in the online documentation of the line chart (marked 1 and 2 in the picture below). Is this version dependent (I am using 3.26.0)?

If anybody has an idea to zoom or change the range, it would be very much apreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

[orange time-series line chart documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q63X.png)

Answer (score 1):

This feature was removed earlier.
https://github.com/biolab/orange3-timeseries/issues/56

Until this is fixed, the workaround that worked for me was to freeze the orange3-timeseries package to 0.3.1
https://pypi.org/project/Orange3-Timeseries/0.3.1/

My Current Orange3 version : 3.26

I can confirm that zoom & pan works on that version.